# Store scalar values (NSInteger, BOOL, double) in CoreData without converting to NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have read a lot of articles where they say to explicitely convert from and to `NSNumber` when I want to store scalars in CoreData:

```objective-c
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger value;

- (NSInteger)value
{
    return [value integerValue];
}

- (void)setValue:(NSInteger)val
{
    value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:val];
}
```

But in our old project we have a bunch of properties where we doesn't do those manipulations (and they don't have custom accessors)! Why it works?

### Example code

Declaration. Scalar values are not transient.

```objective-c
@interface ProductProperty : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString * propertyID;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSSet * values;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL filter;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSDate *update;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSNumber *index;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL system;

@end


#import "ProductProperty.h"

@implementation ProductProperty

@dynamic propertyID;
@dynamic title;
@dynamic values;
@dynamic filter;
@dynamic update;
@dynamic index;
@dynamic system;

@end
```

Mapping into objects. Called if received JSON differs from existing. Otherwise it fetches from the CoreData storage.

```objective-c
- (void)updateProperties:(NSArray*)properties
{
    for (NSDictionary *_property in properties) {
        NSString *propertyID = [_property objectForKey:@"id"];

        ProductProperty *property = [state.productPropertiesWithIDs objectForKey:propertyID];
        if (!property) {
            property = [state.ctx newObjectWithEntityName:ProductProperty.entityName];
            property.propertyID = propertyID;
            [state.productPropertiesWithIDs setObject:property forKey:propertyID];
        }

        property.update = state.update;
        property.title = [_property objectForKey:@"title"];
        property.filter = [_property objectForKey:@"filter"] ? [[_property objectForKey:@"filter"] boolValue] : YES;
        property.index = [propertyIndexes objectForKey:propertyID] ? [propertyIndexes objectForKey:propertyID] : [NSNumber numberWithInt:propertyIndex++];
        property.system = [SYSTEM_PROPERTY_IDS containsObject:propertyID] ? YES : NO;

        [self updatePropertyValues:[_property objectForKey:@"values"] forProperty:property];
    }
}

- (ProductProperty*)productPropertyWithID:(NSString*)propertyId error:(NSError**)error
{
    NSFetchRequest *req = [ProductProperty request];
    req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"propertyID == %@", propertyId];
    return [[ctx executeFetchRequest:req error:error] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: @Saphrosit I've added code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that since iOS 5 CoreData support auto generating accessors for scalars so I don't need to implement them manually.